# Is it possible to change gnuplot polar axes default range from 0-360 to -180 to 180

Tags: range, gnuplot, default, polar-coordinates

Gnuplot default range for polar coordinates is 0-360. Is it possible to change this default, and if so where?

Answer (score 1):

Polar coordinates are interpreted as [t;r].  The default range of the independent variable t (trange) is [0:2pi], or if you have previously said `set angle degrees` then trange defaults to [0:360]. The default is just that, a default.  You can set the range to anything you like before plotting.  If you want tic labels for t and r you may need to set the tic range to match.  If you plan to use these same settings for many plots, you might put some subset of the preparatory commands in your ~/.gnuplot startup file or in a configuration file that can be loaded prior to plotting `load "polar_layout.gp";  plot t`

```
set polar
set angle degrees
set trange [-180:180]
# turn off x/y border and labels
unset border; unset tics
# turn on polar border and axis labels as needed
set border polar
set grid polar
set ttics -150,30,150
set rtics 30
# aspect ration of plot (a circle should look circular)
set size square

plot t
```

[image]

Comment: Doh. Thank you. trange.